# How to get any page of results in one request?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am exploring this function: [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Is it possible to get any page of results without iterating through `nextPageToken`?

E.g. if I display 20 items per page, how do I get items 180-200 for the tenth page without retrieving all the pages inbetween?

On what does the token value for next page depend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like page tokens can be cached. The value of the page tokens doesn't seems to change with time and with the query term. It depends on the maxResults parameter (how many results to retrieve per page). So if you use the same page size for your queries hardcoding the values in the source seems like a working solution.